# Using one error message <h:message> for validation of multiple components with JSF

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I have 3 different components and, when all the fields are empty or at least one of them fails the validation, they are supposed to turn red and show an appropriate message. But, I am not able to make it work, the way I have it the error message shows only if the third textbox fails the validation.
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpnJr.jpg) and
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9wAo.jpg)

Is there away to do this with JSF? if not what are the other alternatives?

< h:inputText id="area_code" name="phone"  required="true" requiredMessage="error msg." validatorMessage="error msg"  >

```
 <f:validateRegex pattern="^[0-9]{3}$" for="area_code"/>    

 <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="3"/>  

 <f:ajax event="blur" render="local_4_msg" execute="local_4"/>
```

< /h:inputText>

< h:inputText id="local_3" name="phone" required="true"  maxlength="3" requiredMessage="error msg." validatorMessage="error msg2." >

```
   <f:validateRegex pattern="^[0-9]{3}$" for="local_3"/>

  <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="3"/>    

   <f:ajax event="blur" execute="local_4" render="local_4_msg"/>
```

< /h:inputText>

< h:inputText id="local_4" name="phone" required="true" requiredMessage="error msg" validatorMessage="error msg2" maxlength="4" >

```
  <f:validateRegex pattern="^[0-9]{4}$" for="local_4"/>   

  <f:validateLength minimum="4" maximum="4"/>    

 <f:ajax event="blur" execute="local_4" render="local_4_msg"/>
```

< /h:inputText>

< h:message for="local_4" id="local_4_msg" styleClass="errormsg" />

Comment: You could by creating a custom validator, but probably it will be easier to start using https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml

Comment: You can have a look at http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateMultiple to get you started creating your validator

Comment: Or just add an `<h:message/>` for each input (or use `<h:messages/>`).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, omnifaces seems more like what I needed, however I am trying to keep my project as light as possible and don't want to add more dependencies. I was wondering if I could do the same with either primefaces or JSF itself? @JasperdeVries

Comment: See my first comment

Comment: @axemoi, I tried adding separate messages however, I ended up having three separate messages, for every validation that failed.